# Can't get rectangles to merge or exit? (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having trouble with the Enter, Update, Exit methodology for D3.js. I can't get my rectangles to update or exit. I am I doing something wrong? I also don't really understand update or exit - what determines if a shape gets exited or updated? What is merge? I think the enter part of the script is working correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 selections</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css">
  </head>

  <body>


    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
          <h1>D3 Selection Exercise</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid directions">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <h2>This exercise </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">D3 Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- create SVG with 4 rectangles -->

    <svg id="mysvg" width="1438" height="726">
      <rect x="50" y="30" width="30" height="100" style="fill: #2980b9;stroke-width:3;stroke:#bdc3c7" />
      <rect x="250" y="30" width="30" height="100" style="fill:#2980b9;stroke-width:3;stroke:#bdc3c7" />
      <rect x="500" y="30" width="30" height="100" style="fill:#2980b9;stroke-width:3;stroke:#bdc3c7" />
      <rect x="750" y="30" width="30" height="100" style="fill:#2980b9;stroke-width:3;stroke:#bdc3c7" />
    </svg>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JQuery click event on button -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $("button").click(function(){
          draw([2, 4, 6, 8, 27]);
        });
      });

      var svg = d3.select("#mysvg")
        .attr("width", window.innerWidth)
        .attr("height", window.innerHeight);

    // Draw function

      function draw(dataArray) {
        var rectangles = svg.selectAll("rect")
          .data(dataArray);

    // Exit
          rectangles.exit()
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .attr("width", 0)
            .attr("height", 0)
            .attr("fill", "red")
            .remove();

    // Enter
            var enterRectangles = rectangles.enter().append("rect")
              .attr("width", 30)
              .attr("height", 100)
              .attr("y", 30)
              .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return 750 + (50 * (i + 1));
              })
              .style("fill", "#2980b9")
              .style("stroke-width", "3")
              .style("stroke", "#bdc3c7" );

      // Update

          rectangles.merge(enterRectangles)
              .transition().duration(1000)
              .attr("height", function(d) {
                return d;
                })
              .attr("fill", "green");

      };

    </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried reading some of Mike Bostock's works like this one https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218? Also let us know what you want the end product to look like so we can help direct you there

Comment: Yeah, I've read a lot of his works, including that link. I don't understand why my rectangles aren't exiting, or what exit is even for? Is the update working?

Comment: But they are updating. The exit selection has `0` length and the enter selection has `1` element. Here it is, I'm multiplying `d * 5` so you can better see it: https://jsfiddle.net/j1xnz3y1/1/

Comment: ok, thank you for this!